# Logm is not defined

Tags: python

I keep getting an error: logm is not defined for the below. Any ideas for why this is not working? Am I importing an incorrect module?

```
import re
import pandas as pd
beer = pd.read_csv('http://www-958.ibm.com/software/analytics/manyeyes/datasets/af-er-beer-dataset/versions/1.txt', delimiter="\t")
beer = beer.dropna()
def good(x):
  if x > 4.3:
  return 1
  else:
  return 0
beer['Good'] = beer['WR'].apply(good)
```

The above works well. I find the error if I try to run the below:

```
input = beer[ ['Reviews', 'ABV'] ].values
good = beer['Good'].values
logm.fit(input, good)
logm.predict(input)
logm.score(input, good)

input = beer[ ['Ale', 'Stout', 'IPA', 'Lager'] ].values
y = beer['Good'].values

logm.fit(input, y)
```

Comment: Well, you never defined what `logm` is

Comment: Did you intend to `from scipy.linalg import logm`?

Comment: Thanks @kojiro - I added that and it got rid of the error. I then tried to run logm.fit(input, good) and it said: 'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fit''

Comment: Then perhaps the scipy logm wasn't the logm you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use scikit-learn's Logistic Regression. You are missing the following:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
logm = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
```